# How to make socket connection for remote IP ? (I know how to do it for Local IP)

Tags: java

How to make socket connection for remote IP? I know how to do it with a local IP.

My code for local IP  is:

```
package com.asmaitha.client;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.Finishings;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Client {

    static Socket s,socket;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    DataOutputStream datOutputStream;
    static TextArea tarea;
    String dataFromServer;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
   class MyClient1 extends SwingWorker<String,String>
   {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try 
            {
//              InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress("110.234.149.86",null);//getByName("110.234.149.86") ;
//              tarea.setText(serverAddress.getCanonicalHostName());
                System.out.println("calling socket");
                socket = new Socket("192.168.1.31",8080);
                if(socket != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("ContentApp"+ "Socket Successfully created");
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("ContentApp"+ "Socket IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try 
            {
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("ContentApp"+ "DataInputstream Successfully created");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("ContentApp"+ "Datainputstream failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
//              return false;
            }
            try
            {
                datOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                datOutputStream.writeUTF("Hi This is client!");
                System.out.println("ContentApp"+ "Dataoutputstream Successfully created");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("ContentApp"+ "Dataoutputstream failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
//              return false;
            }

            if(socket != null)
            {
               while(socket!=null)
               {
                dataFromServer = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                done();
               }
            }
            return dataFromServer; 
            }
        @Override
        protected void done() {
        if (dataFromServer != null)
        {
            tarea.setText("");
        tarea.append(dataFromServer);
        }
        else
        tarea.append("no value from server !");
        }

        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("calling theframe");
        Frame frame=new Frame("Button Frame");
        tarea = new TextArea("",5,40);
        frame.add(tarea);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("calling the Client");
        Client c = new Client();
        MyClient1 myClient = c.new MyClient1() ;

        myClient.execute();

        /*Client1 client = new Client1();
        if(client == null)
        {
            System.out.println("client isnull");
            return;
        }
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(client);
        if(clientThread!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("strating clent1");
            clientThread.start();
        }*/



        /*try {
            s = new Socket("110.234.149.86",8080);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a connection to an IP address `new Socket("192.168.1.31",8080);` All you have to do is change the address or give it a resolvable host name.

I assume this is not working for you. What is your actual problem when you try to do this?

I assume you are on a local network behind a firewall.  Is your network set up to access the remote address you want to connect to?

Comment: as you suggested i am tried like this new Socket("Myremoteseveraddress",8080); but it socket timeout is coming

Comment: It is quite likely that your machine on your network cannot connect to that server.  Until it can do so, i.e. firewalls and networks are setup to allow this, there is nothing you can do in Java to workaround this. On the command line try `telnet Myremoteseveraddress 8080`. This has to work first.

Comment: You have to determine why you cannot connect to this host and fix it. If you have a mouse which is not plugged in, nothing in Java will let you use that mouse. ;)

Comment: Can you resolve the hostname? Can you ping the host? Can you ping another host from that machine?

Comment: Yes i can ping the Local host but for Remote IP i cant can u suggest any soluction or code

Comment: `Can you resolve the hostname?` When you try to ping it does it show you the IP address, what error do you get? This NOT something you can fix in code, you have setup your OS/hardware correctly.

Comment: I am having the IP Address of my remote server i can see it through browser, but can not create socket connection

Comment: The browser can use a proxy server which means only the proxy server needs to be able to resolve or connect to the host. Are you using a proxy server?

Comment: InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName("110.234.149.86"); socket = new Socket(serverAddress,5757) ;                            The Remote Socket will Connect for U and You should make FireWalls off